# Hibernate 5.3 regression with ehcache replication and Composite ID

Tags: hibernate, replication, ehcache, jgroups

We are using the following components

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.6:compile
net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-jgroupsreplication:jar:1.7:compile
org.jgroups:jgroups:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
```

We have an Entity with a composite ID:

```
@Entity
@Cache(region = ReplicatedCacheConfiguration.NAME, usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class SpielErgebnis {
    @EmbeddedId
    protected SpielErgebnisId spielErgebnisId;
  …
}
@Embeddable
public class SpielErgebnisId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Integer spielId;
    public Integer spielabschnittId;
  …
}
```

Or cache is replicated with Jgroups, but does only send invalidation messages:

```
replicateAsynchronously=true
replicatePuts=false
replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false
```

When one of these entities is changed and a "remove" message must be send the receiving side does not accept the message and throws an exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find a
>   SessionFactory [uuid=a1d8234c-1c14-4ba5-b429-d026fd2e6197,name=null]

This happens since we upgraded from hibernate version 5.2.17 to 5.3.7. It happens with 5.4.x too.

This is the complete stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   Could not find a SessionFactory
>   [uuid=e440a601-e5d0-4e9d-b4ce-94105b545106,name=null]     at
>   org.jgroups.Message.getObject(Message.java:383)   at
>   org.jgroups.Message.getObject(Message.java:363)   at
>   net.sf.ehcache.distribution.jgroups.JGroupsCacheReceiver.receive(JGroupsCacheReceiver.java:64)
>     at org.jgroups.JChannel.invokeCallback(JChannel.java:817)   at
>   org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:741)    at
>   org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1029)   at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:1045)    at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG.up(FRAG.java:149)  at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:234)   at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST.up(UNICAST.java:402)    at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.handleMessage(NAKACK.java:790)    at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK.up(NAKACK.java:602)   at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:155)  at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:310)    at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE2.up(MERGE2.java:237)  at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:295)    at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1577)  at
>   org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1796)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not find a SessionFactory
>   [uuid=e440a601-e5d0-4e9d-b4ce-94105b545106,name=null]     at
>   org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration$Scope.readResolve(TypeConfiguration.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadResolve(ObjectStreamClass.java:1260)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2078)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1975)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>     at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
>     at org.jgroups.util.Util.objectFromByteBuffer(Util.java:485)    at
>   org.jgroups.Message.getObject(Message.java:380)   ... 20 common frames
>   omitted

The error is thrown in [TypeConfiguration](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/823a5c1ede1869fd97471e3b8ebe7ec4ac8068e4/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/type/spi/TypeConfiguration.java#L367) which is available since 5.3

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this bug when you give your session factory a name. In Spring Boot2 with Tomcat it is not easy as tomcats jndi is not enabled by default.

Enable Naming in Tomcat with a Spring Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class JndiConfig {
    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected TomcatWebServer getTomcatWebServer(Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatWebServer(tomcat);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then add a property to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.session_factory_name=kicktipp
```

With a session factory name hibernate is happy to except the message and works as it should.

Additional: If you still get an error about reflection issue this might be a  classloader issue in your IDE. I had this with Intellij and running two instances of my SpringBootApplication:

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error
>   accessing field [public java.lang.Integer
>   …SpielErgebnisId.spielId] by
>   reflection for persistent property

This is a classloading issue because of spring-boot-devtools. If you remove it from the classpath, the replication works fine.